# bootstrap, with 3 cols I need left col fixed width and float left, right col fixed width and float right and middle col to 100%

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have 3 columns (similar to twitter). The left column needs to maintain a minimum width of 312 pixels, the center column will be set to maximum 650 pixels and act normally when the screen is resized. (ie: it will collapse in width as needed) the right column will be like the left and maintain a minimum 312 pixel width. I would like to float the left col to the left, float the right col to the right and set the center col to 100% width. Can this be done?

The text boxes in the center column is the only one that receives user input.

In summary the center will decrease in width and the right and left will maintain a minimum width.

Layout image needed for reference

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're locked into Bootstrap 4, then you could achieve this layout via the [flex utility classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/) that Bootstrap 4 provides.

You will likely still need to supply some custom CSS for the dimensions your require. See code below:

HTML:

```
<!-- reuse flex classes provided by boostrap 4 -->
<div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-between">

  <div class="left">
    Left side content
  </div>

  <div class="center">
    Center content
  </div>

  <div class="right">
    Right side content
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.left, .right {  
  width:312px; // Target width for left/right content columns
  min-width:312px; // Minimum allowed width for left/right content columns
}

.left {
  background:red; // Colouring to help with visualising layout boundaries
}
.center {
  width:650px; // Target width for center content column 

  background:yellow; // Colouring to help with visualising layout boundaries
}
.right {
  background:green; // Colouring to help with visualising layout boundaries
}
```

Comment: That worked for me with a couple of minor changes.. Thank you so much for leading me in the right direction.

Comment: Excellent - great to hear. All the best with your project :-)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirements correctly, this can be achieved in a number of ways. One such way is via CSS flex-box.

Consider the following HTML and CSS to see how the foundation of your required layout could be defined:

HTML:

```
<div class="row">

  <div class="left">
    Left side content
  </div>

  <div class="center">
    Center content
  </div>

  <div class="right">
    Right side content
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  text-align:center;
}

.row {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.left, .right {  
  width:312px; // Target width for left/right content columns
  min-width:312px; // Minimum allowed width for left/right content columns
}

.left {
  background:red; // Colouring to help with visualising layout boundaries
}
.center {
  width:650px; // Target width for center content column 

  background:yellow; // Colouring to help with visualising layout boundaries
}
.right {
  background:green; // Colouring to help with visualising layout boundaries
}
```

Comment: Dacre Denny that solution actually works thanks but I am locked into Bootstrap not Flex. i hope there is a Bootstrap solution.